# KKT-Conditions in a functional setting

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $F:L^2([0,1])\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex functional.
Consider the minimization problem 
\begin{align}
   \underset{f(\cdot) \in L^2([0,1])}{\min} F(f)\,\,\text{ subject to }
     \|f(\cdot) \|_2\leq \lambda,
\end{align}
with $\lambda>0$ and $\|f(\cdot) \|_2=\int_0^1 f\left(t\right)^2\text{d} t  $. Are there some kind of KKT conditions for the minimizer of $F$?

You can even consider $F$ as linear if that‘s easier.

Comment: What does $\|f(\cdot)\|\le \lambda$ mean? In any case, you can write the problem as $\min_f F(f) + I_C(f)$, where $I_C$ is the indicator function of the set defined by the inequality. Then apply subdifferential sum rule.

Comment: I edited the question. $\|f\left(\cdot\right)\|_2$ is the $L_2$-norm.